# Circular Content Carousel Style

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to use circular content carousel style in my web page. I have two photo albums to display using this style. I can display one, but I can not apply the same to the other album. I tried this by coping and pasting the same code in the body of my html code.

Do I have to modify the code after pasting the same for the second time?

(My first album is working properly like this. I want to apply the same style for another set of images in same web page.
http://tympanus.net/Development/CircularContentCarousel/)

Following is my code of the .

```
<body>
<div class>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row about">
      <div class="col-md-8">
             <h3 class="m_2">Show Rooms</h3>
            <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
                <div class="ca-wrapper">
                     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                       <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon1"> </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon2"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon3"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon4"> </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon5"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon6"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon7"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
         </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
                </script>
       </div>
       <div class="row about">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3 class="m_2"> Cricket</h3>
            <div id="ca-container1" class="ca-container1">
                <div class="ca-wrapper">
                     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                       <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon1"> </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon2"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon3"> </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon6"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon7"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                            <div class="ca-icon"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
                </script>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```
    </body>
```

Comment: Hi, post code please! Context especially in the form of code is crucial and much appreciated (and actually expected), and needed to help answer questions about code!

Answer (score 0):

In the carousal at given [url](http://tympanus.net/Development/CircularContentCarousel/), there is an **id** given to container **div**, i.e. *#ca-container*. May be the carousel script is referring the same id for creating the functionality and because of repeating id in same page your carousel is not working.

Try using different ids or using a common class while calling the carousel script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried by changing the 'id'. But it didn't work. Do I have to do something in css file as well.

Comment: In your given code, the second carousel div has id '#ca-container1' and in the relevant script that you are calling, there is still '#ca-container'. Change it to $('#ca-container1').contentcarousel();